# How to get the index of a type in a variadic type pack?

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates

For example

```
template<typename T, typename... Ts>
struct Index
{
    enum {value = ???}
};
```

and assume T is one of Ts and Ts has different types, like

```
Index<int, int, double>::value is 0
Index<double, int, double>::value is 1
```

Comment: This is almost a duplicate of your question from last year: [Get index of a tuple element's type?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18063451)

Comment: @dyp (Ask a question about variardics, ++year)`...`

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <cstddef>

template <typename T, typename... Ts>
struct Index;

template <typename T, typename... Ts>
struct Index<T, T, Ts...> : std::integral_constant<std::size_t, 0> {};

template <typename T, typename U, typename... Ts>
struct Index<T, U, Ts...> : std::integral_constant<std::size_t, 1 + Index<T, Ts...>::value> {};
```

You might like to add a [c++14](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b14) variable template:

```
template <typename T, typename... Ts>
constexpr std::size_t Index_v = Index<T, Ts...>::value;
```

[**DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d37fec17d2490ae2)