# Reverse variadic template arguments in hierarchy

Tags: c++, c++11

I currently have this class which uses typelist:

```
template<class AbstractF, template<class, class > class Creator, class TList>
class A: public B<typename Reverse<TList>::Result, Creator, AbstractF> {
};
```

I'm trying to make the code more c++11 friendly replacing the typelist with variadic template arguments.

```
template<class AbstractF, template<class, class > class Creator, class TList...>
class A: public B<Creator, AbstractF, TList...> { //<---how to reverse here?
};
```

The problem is: how to reverse a variadic list? Looking at other questions I saw the use of `std::tuple`, but in this case I'm not able to understand how to "unpack" it since the variadic arguments are not part of simple templated function but they are used as arguments in a class hierarchy.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to reverse the order of arguments of a variadic template function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15904288/how-to-reverse-the-order-of-arguments-of-a-variadic-template-function)

Comment: @DanM.No actually, as I said everything is applicable to a function, but in this case there's no function involved, just a list of types used in a class hierarchy.

Comment: If all the types are distinct, there is a simple solution. If they are not, you can't do it without indirection.

Comment: @Evg They should be distinct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all the types in the pack are distinct, you can compute the type's `index` from the type itself. All that remains is to extract the `N - 1 - index`'th type from the pack:

```
template<std::size_t index, class... Ts>
using Nth_type = std::tuple_element_t<index, std::tuple<Ts...>>;

template<class S, class... Ts>
inline constexpr std::size_t type_index = 0;

template<class S, class T, class... Ts>
inline constexpr std::size_t type_index<S, T, Ts...> = 
    std::is_same_v<S, T> ? 0 : 1 + type_index<S, Ts...>;

template<class T, class... Ts>
using Reverser = Nth_type<sizeof...(Ts) - 1 - type_index<T, Ts...>, Ts...>;
```

Simple example:

```
template<class... Ts>
class B;

template<class... Ts>
using RB = B<Reverser<Ts, Ts...>...>;   // two pack expansions here

static_assert(std::is_same<RB<>, B<>>());
static_assert(std::is_same<RB<int>, B<int>>());
static_assert(std::is_same<RB<int, float, double>, B<double, float, int>>());
```

If the pack is allowed to contain identical types, this trick won't work.

This code uses some C++14/17 features. Variable templates are not part of C++11, so `type_index` has to be implemented differently. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26169248/1625187) is a possible implementation.

Comment: I just add that std::tuple_element_t is c++14

Comment: Not mandatory but I'd like to have code works even on old compilers

Comment: @greywolf82, then `type_index` should be reimplemented using class templates. I updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm trying to make the code more c++11 friendly replacing the typelist with variadic template arguments

If you use the old typelist way (the link list of type)
then in C++11, you can even use unpacked variadic template arguments, or packed variadic template arguments inside `std::tuple` or similar.

Unpacked way has limitation about manipulations (transformation, skip head, concatenation), and working first with packing way might be needed.

For reordering, packing way might be:

```
template <typename TypeList, typename Seq> struct ReverseImpl;

template <typename TypeList, std::size_t ... Is>
struct ReverseImpl<TypeList, std::index_sequence<Is...>>
{
    using type = std::tuple<typename std::tuple_element<sizeof...(Is) - 1 - Is, TypeList>::type...>;
};


template <typename TypeList> struct Reverse
{
    using Result =
        typename ReverseImpl<TypeList,
                             std::make_index_sequence<std::tuple_size<TypeList>::value>>::type;
};
```

Note: `std::index_sequence`/`std::make_index_sequence` are C++14, but can be implemented in C++11.

Possible usage might be:

```
template <template<class, class > class Creator, class AbstractF, typename TypeList>
struct BUnpack;

template<template<class, class > class Creator, class AbstractF, typename ... Ts>
class BUnpack<Creator, AbstractF, std::tuple<Ts...>>
{
    using type = B<Creator, AbstractF, Ts...>;
};

template<class AbstractF, template<class, class > class Creator, typename ... Ts>
class A: public BUnpack<Creator, AbstractF, typename Reverse<std::tuple<Ts...>>::Result>::type {
};
```