# How can I get the index of a type in a variadic class template?

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates

I have a variadic Engine template class:

```
template <typename ... Components> class Engine;
```

I'd like to assign a number to each component at compile time which is equivalent to their ordering. This would be returned when making the following call:

```
template <typename Component> int ordinal();
```

So for example if:

```
Engine<PositionComponent, PhysicsComponent, InputComponent> engine;
```

was declared, the call:

```
engine.ordinal<PhysicsComponent>();
```

would return 1 and a similar call with InputComponent instead of PhysicsComponent would return 2.

Is it possible, and if yes, how would one go about it?

Comment: I found [this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18063451/get-index-of-a-tuple-elements-type) for tuples, I'm pretty sure you can adapt it for your use case.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In [Boost.Mp11](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/develop/libs/mp11/doc/html/mp11.html#mp_findl_v), this is a short one-liner (as always):

```cpp
template <typename... Components>
struct Engine {
    template <typename Component>
    static constexpr int ordinal() {
        return mp_find<Engine, Component>::value;
    }
};
```

Note that if `Component` is absent, this will return `sizeof...(Components)`. If desired, you can add a static assertion to verify this.

My original answer follows below the fold...

---

So you want to find the index of `Component` in `Components...`?

```
template <typename... >
struct index;

// found it
template <typename T, typename... R>
struct index<T, T, R...>
: std::integral_constant<size_t, 0>
{ };

// still looking
template <typename T, typename F, typename... R>
struct index<T, F, R...>
: std::integral_constant<size_t, 1 + index<T,R...>::value>
{ };
```

Usage:

```
template <typename Component> 
size_t ordinal() { return index<Component, Components...>::value; }
```

As constructed, trying to get the `ordinal` of a `Component` not in `Components...` will be a compile error. Which seems appropriate.

Comment: Very clever solution by adding the result of `index<T,R...>::value` to 1!

Comment: Thanks. This is great. Do you know if the compiler will optimise the template iteration away?

Comment: @NickCuthbert It will have to compile it all, but `index<Component, Components...>::value` is a compile-time constant - there is no runtime work involved there.

Comment: Good answer, but still you should add a case where the index is not actually found, which should perhaps return -1 or generate a static assertion.

Comment: Also a case with an empty variadic pack is not handles appropriately.

Answer (score 2):

My goal below is to keep things in the compile-time realm as much as possible.

This is an alias to remove some boilerplate.  `std::integral_constant` is a wonderful `std` type that stores a compile-time determined integer-type:

```
template<std::size_t I>
using size=std::integral_constant<std::size_t, I>;
```

Next, a `index_of` type, and an `index_of_t` that is slightly easier to use:

```
template<class...>struct types{using type=types;};
template<class T, class Types>struct index_of{};
template<class T, class...Ts>
struct index_of<T, types<T, Ts...>>:size<0>{};
template<class T, class T0, class...Ts>
struct index_of<T, types<T0, Ts...>>:size<
  index_of<T,types<Ts...>>::value +1
>{};
```

This alias returns a pure `std::integral_constant`, instead of a type inheriting from it:

```
template<class T, class...Ts>
using index_of_t = size< index_of<T, types<Ts...>>::value >;
```

Finally our function:

```
template <class Component>
static constexpr index_of_t<Component, Components...>
ordinal() const {return{};}
```

it is not only `constexpr`, it returns a value that encodes its value in its type.  `size<?>` has a `constexpr operator size_t()` as well as an `operator()`, so you can use it in most spots that expect integer types seamlessly.

You could also use:

```
template<class Component>
using ordinal = index_of_t<Component, Components...>;
```

and now `ordinal<Component>` is a type representing the index of the component, instead of a function.

Answer (score 1):

I'm adding this for completeness sake, it utilizes C++11's constexpr  functionality, and a few stl functions. I feel it is a little cleaner than the other solutions.

```
//Same type
template <typename Target,typename T,typename ...Rest>
constexpr typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<Target,T>::value, size_t>
_ordinal(){
    return 0;
}

//Different types
template <typename Target,typename T,typename ...Rest>
constexpr typename std::enable_if<!std::is_same<Target,T>::value, size_t>
_ordinal(){
    return 1+_ordinal<Target,Rest...>();
}
```

Comment: You are missing `::type` part from the `std::enable_if` (even though you do have the `typename` there).

Comment: Also the compilation error when the type looked for is not on the list is rather unfriendly I think (at least with GCC 6.3.0). And it doesn't say much about the real issue. Although I'm not sure how other solutions shown here look like in this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

UNTESTED:

```
template <int, typename>
constexpr int index_of() { return -1; } // type not found

template <int N, typename Component, typename Cur, typename... Components>
constexpr int index_of() {
    return std::is_same<Component, Cur>::value ? N : index_of<N+1, Component, Components...>();
}

template <typename... Components>
template <typename Component>
constexpr int engine<Components...>::ordinal() {
    return index_of<0, Component, Components...>();
}
```

I *could* have used structs, but I find this much cleaner (without all the `::type` ugliness).

If you want a compile-time error when the type is not found, change `ordinal` to:

```
template <typename... Components>
template <typename Component>
constexpr int engine<Components...>::ordinal() {
    static_assert(index_of<0, Component, Components...>()!=-1, "invalid component");
     return index_of<0, Component, Components...>();
}
```